# Ubuntu 16.04 does not wake up from sleep on ASUS Laptop

Tags: suspend, lightdm

I'm running 16.04.1 LTS on an asus laptop. The laptop does not wake up after being suspended(sleep). But the hibernate mode works.

When lightdm service is stopped, sleep mode works normally. However, I can not restart Lightdm.

Ubuntu kernel version: 4.4.0-57-generic

Custom computer specs:

- Laptop model: ASUS A556UQ
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
- VGA: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02) / GM108M [GeForce 940MX]

Comment: I have installed drivers for graphics (nvidia and intel).
I had resume test on my laptop. I found that console mode works after suspend. because able to use ssh to connect to my laptop from another PC. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work: shutdown your laptop from the ubuntu gui. It worked for me.
Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=221224